# Why type arguments cannot be inferred for generic types?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

### Default case

Let's suppose the following exemplary problem - I want **to create a method which will simply output the number of elements in any `List<>` collection**.
I have created the following static class with one method:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod<T>(T obj) where T : List<int> // sort of pointless, yes
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Count);
    }
}
```

Note that `T` is a subclass of `List<int>`. Now, I can call:

```
List<int> li = new List<int>();
MyClass.MyMethod<List<int>>(li);
```

Now, IDE tells me that "Type argument specification is redundant". It can infer the type from usage:

```
List<int> li = new List<int>();
MyClass.MyMethod(li); // OK. li is List<int>, type argument is not required
```

### Generic case

As far as you remember, I want to output the count of `List` of **any** type.   Something like this would be great:

```
public static void MyComplexMethod<T>(T obj) where T : List<any>
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Count);
}
```

However, it is an incorrect syntax. I have to implement the following method:

```
public static void MyComplexMethod<T1, T2>(T1 obj) where T1 : List<T2>
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Count);
}
```

Now, calling this method without describing types explicitly produces an error "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage":

```
List<int> li = new List<int>();
MyClass.MyComplexMethod(li); // error
MyClass.MyComplexMethod<List<int>>(li); // error
MyClass.MyComplexMethod<List<int>, int>(li); // OK

MyClass.MyComplexMethod<List<double>, double>(new List<double>()); // OK
MyClass.MyComplexMethod<List<string>, string>(new List<string>()); // OK

// error. The type must be convertible in order to use...So, compiler knows it
MyClass.MyComplexMethod<List<string>, double>(new List<string>());
```

However, for me it seems like the type should be inferable from usage. I provide `List<int>` - T1 is `List<int>` and T2 is `int`, obviously. Why doesn't compiler can do this? What is the most reasonable way to achieve the desirable behaviour (`where T : List<any>`)?

### Real case

If someone just wonders why I would need this. Actually, I have stumbled upon this case, when I was trying to implement a WCF proxy wrapper, like this:

```
public static void Call<TServiceProxy, TServiceContract>(Action<TServiceProxy> action)
    where TServiceProxy : ClientBase<TServiceContract>, new()
    where TServiceContract : class
{
    TServiceProxy serviceProxy = new TServiceProxy();
    try
    {
        action(serviceProxy);
        serviceProxy.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        serviceProxy.Abort();
        // Log(ex);
        throw;
    }
}

Service.Call<EchoServiceClient>(x => {
    int v = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    x.Echo(v);
}); // not working

Service.Call<EchoServiceClient, IEchoService>(x => {
    int v = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    x.Echo(v);
}); // not convenient, pointless. EchoServiceClient inherits from ClientBase<IEchoService>
```

Without `where TServiceProxy : ClientBase<TServiceContract>` I won't be able to do `serviceProxy.Abort()`. Again, `where TServiceProxy : ClientBase<any>` would be a great solution, because actually `TServiceContract` does not matter - it is only used in `where` constraint.

Comment: you can use an interface and then extend the type , then you can put contraint on interace like ``ClientBase<SomInterface>``

Comment: use `IList` instead of `List<any>`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Great, thanks! For `List<>` the problem is solved. What about a real case? I haven't found something like `IClientBase`.

Comment: Did you try this? `public static void Call<TServiceContract>(Action<ClientBase<TServiceContract>> action)
    where TServiceContract : class`

Comment: @Henrik Then, I won't be able to instantiate a `TServiceProxy proxy = new TSeviceProxy();`

Comment: `public static void MyMethod<T>(List<T> obj) { return obj.Count; }`should works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about what your actual requirements for the type are.

In your case, what do you want to do? You want to be able to execute `action` on a client which you create in the method. That client is of the type you pass as the generic type argument. Do you need to know that it’s a `ClientBase<something>` in order to execute the action? No.

What else do you do on the object? You open and close the channel. Those are actions ensured by [`ICommunicationObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.aspx) which `ClientBase<T>` implements.

That’s all your requirements. So you want to have the following constraints:

- Being able to create an object of the type.
- The type implementing `ICommunicationObject` so you can open/close the channel.

So your method could look like this:

```
public static void Call<T>(Action<T> action)
    where T: ICommunicationObject, new()
{
    T serviceProxy = new T();
    try
    {
        action(serviceProxy);
        serviceProxy.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        serviceProxy.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Finally, to answer your question on why the compiler cannot resolve this automatically: If you have generic type arguments, there are two possibilites. Either the compiler is able to infer *all* type arguments, in which case you can leave them out, or the compiler is not able to infer all arguments in which case you need to specify them all. After all `Foo<X>()` and `Foo<X, Y>()` are different method signatures, so if the latter also allowed `Foo<X>()`, it would be ambiguous.

As for why the compiler cannot infer *all* type arguments in your case, this is simply because relationships between type arguments given by the constraints are not evaluated for the type inferring.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer! It sounds logical after you explained this. Solution with `ICommunicationObject` works great as well :)

Comment: It seems interfaces are useful in generic methods. good point. @YeldarKurmangaliyev